# MS VC++ 6 command line compile gets error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some projects tethered to MS VC6 [I understand it's a 10+ yr old compiler. I understand it's got some issues. It's what I have to work with, for now.]

In an attempt to automate some builds, I'm trying to get the msdev command-line compile to work.  Everything looks to be working UNTIL the end, when it errors on the file 'afxres.h'.

This is an MFC project, and I do have the full VC6 compiler installed. (Project builds fine in the IDE.)  I've seen some on-line questions where an "Express" compiler withOUT MFC support is trying to be used, but that's NOT my case.

I'm seeing some Interwebs forum q/a that seems to be alluding to an issue with "include path too long" in the VC6 compiler.  The only solution I've found is "Make your include path shorter" but ...how can that possibly be a realistic option??  I don't think I have extraneous paths!

http://www.ms-news.net/f3291/compiler-fatal-error-rc1015-cannot-open-include-file-afxres-h-2526453.html

Does ANYONE have any other ideas for me?  I'm kind of at a loss here.  Plus the solution they're suggesting ["The workaround I found was to copy all the /I compile options generated by the C/C++.General.Additional Include Directories entry and move them into the C/C++.CommandLine.Additional Options"] does NOT seem to have an equivalent "CommandLine Additional Options" in VC6?

Thanks everyone!! 
Craig

UPDATE: it does in fact seem to be somehow related to my NOT having run the vcvars32.bat file, and other include/library environment variable errors.... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

RC1015 is generated by the resource compiler, not the C++ compiler. I don't know how the include path is configured, but it appears to be out of sync with your C++ include path.